# Noob question deleted by community within 15 minutes?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24521791/php-echo-making-some-letters-lowercase), which is pretty noobish in nature.

It received some downvotes and closevotes as per normal, because the fix is somewhat typo related and won't help future users.

However, it was deleted by Community within 15 minutes of its existence! I've seen this happen with spam questions before, but not with legit questions like the aforementioned.

So did this question get flagged as spam, then?

Comment: The user got deleted. Depending on how this happens, it may or may not take all the negatively voted questions with it. (I'm unsure of the details.)

Comment: Ah, so depending on why the user's was deleted then ... that sounds plausible :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Mysticial notes, when user accounts are deleted any and all downvoted posts they've made go with them.

So that's what happened here.

There've been some concerns raised over the years about the potential for collateral damage, but by and large this just serves to remove a whole bunch of crap that no one is ever going to fix.

Comment: Ah, so I guess that's what happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699590/put-a-doclick-inside-a-joptionpane), because the question didn't seem that bad to me (and my answer of course was wonderful).

Comment: ... joking about the "wonderful" part, although I do have wonder what the poor OP did to be whacked so hard by the Community user.